# Unknown Column 'B.in_out' in on clause MySQL

Tags: mysql

I already confused about how to left join same table, I make left join query like this :

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN A.time BETWEEN '06:15:00' AND '11:59:00' THEN "IN"
WHEN A.time BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:00' THEN "OUT"
WHEN A.time BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:14:00' THEN "OUT"
END in_out, A.no_reg, A.date, A.date_time AS time_in, B.date_time AS time_out
FROM raw_attendance A
LEFT JOIN raw_attendance B
   ON A.no_reg = B.no_reg
      AND A.date_time < B.date_time
      AND B.in_out = 'OUT'
HAVING A.in_out = 'IN'
```

But the result is :

```
Unknown column 'B.in_out' in 'on clause'
```

Anyone can help me to tell me where I miss my query, so I make some error? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to reuse an aliased `CASE` expression defined in a select clause, in a `WHERE` clause at the same level.  Here is one workaround for what I think you are trying to do here:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN A.time BETWEEN '06:15:00' AND '11:59:00' THEN 'IN'
         WHEN A.time BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:00' THEN 'OUT'
         WHEN A.time BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:14:00' THEN 'OUT' END in_out,
    A.no_reg,
    A.date,
    A.date_time AS time_in,
    B.date_time AS time_out
FROM raw_attendance A
LEFT JOIN raw_attendance B
    ON A.no_reg = B.no_reg AND
       A.date_time < B.date_time AND
       (B.time BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:14:00' OR
        B.time BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:00')
WHERE
    A.time BETWEEN '06:15:00' AND '11:59:00';
```

In this version, rather than trying to reuse the `CASE` expression, I simply include the original range checks which were determining either an `IN` or `OUT` result.  If you really wanted to reuse the `CASE` expression, you might have to subquery.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I understand about your explanation, so I can't using alias in CASE? I must make an another way to get same logic in CASE clause without using alias right?

Comment: @LuckALip Well, as you were partially doing in your original query, you _can_ refer to aliases in the `HAVING` clause.  The problem here is that you were also needing to use that alias in the join condition, where it definitely isn't available.  The typical workaround, as my answer suggests, would be to subquery your current query, and then reuse the alias.

Comment: so I must using subquery into my current query to using the alias? Thank you

Comment: Yes, other than that `HAVING` clause (which won't work in your case), subquery is the only option.  Well, that, and also using a common table expression (CTE), if you're running MySQL 8+ or later.

Comment: Oh ya, is alias can use in `GROUP BY`?